# CSS calc() is it widely supported?

Tags: html, css, css-calc

Since I have learned how to use `calc` in CSS, I have found many instances where it has been useful to me.

However, I am wondering how it performs across browsers and devices.

Is it supported widely enough to use without worrying about?

**Demo:**

```css
.element {
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

Comment: [The compatibility is not so wide](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)... you should go for javascript solutions if you want your application to run nice on legacy machines.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes you seem to have a very narrow definition of wide support. The site you linked to shows greater than 78% browser support o_0

Comment: I meant for older browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) it is well supported, just doesn't support IE8 and Opera Mini Browser, and an earlier version of Android (4.3), where most of modern Android devices are within version 4.4 to 6

If you take a look, you will see that using it **unprefixed** is:

- 75% supported + 3% partial supported, performing a 78% total.

[image: SS]

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the website.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little open-ended. Generally you aren't supposed to post something that doesn't have a concrete answer. That said:

[Can I use: calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Calc is pretty widely supported except in IE8 and below. Up to you if it's worth it. I use it at times, depending on the project.